# RecursiveIterator with directories in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, recursiveiterator

I want to list directories and files in directories like:

```
Array(
    [0] => 2014
    [1] => images
    [2] => videos
)
```

All of the directories in this array are in the "web_public" directory of my website. But there are some other directories within it which I don't want to read. The complete web_public is:

```
2014
images
videos
css
js
... and so on
```

Here is what I'm doing but doesn't work:

```
$objects = array();
foreach($dirs_to_read as $dir) {
    $dir = 'web_public/'.$dir;
    $objects = array_merge($objects, new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));                
}   
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($objects);
```

Comment: `new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)` returns an object (not an array) so you can't use it as `array_merge` second argument. Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php

Comment: Yes I saw that with a print_r but I don't find a way to fix it.

Comment: If you want this level of control you can't use RecursiveDirectoryIterator() - I wrote my own class (pfpFileTree - available at http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6856-PHP-Manipulates-files-in-directories-recursively.html ). While the data is held in a public variable (you can use array_ functions) the class is explicitly designed to allow filtering, adding and editing of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP 5 you can use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) to get file array. For example:

```
$path = __DIR__;

$directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $path,
    RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    | RecursiveDirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME
    | RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME
);

$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$array    = iterator_to_array($iterator);

print_r($array);
```

Outputs something like:

```
Array
(
    [demo.php] => /path/tp/demo.php
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This calls for use of the [`AppendIterator`](http://php.net/AppendIterator). Example usage:

```
$ai = new AppendIterator;
foreach( $dirs_to_read as $dir )
{
    // append RecursiveDirectoryIterator (wrapped in RecursiveIteratorIterator)
    // you need RecursiveIteratorIterator as well,
    // to iterate all depths of the RecursiveDirectoryIterator, in one go
    $ai->append( new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( 'web_public/' . $dir ),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    ) );
}

// iterate the AppendIterator
foreach( $ai as $file )
{
    /* do something with the file (which is an SplFileInfo instance) */
}
```